# Perché "vendesi" e non "si vende"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, pronouns

Gli annunci immobiliari italiani mi sono sempre sembrati molto curiosi. Perché si scrive "vendesi" o "affittasi" e non "si vende" o "si affitta"?

Comment: Un tempo era normale, nella lingua scritta, posporre il pronome riflessivo. Era anche comodo negli annunci commerciali, pagati a numero di parole, ed è purtroppo rimasto nel linguaggio immobiliare.

Comment: E attenzione al fatto che il plurale è ovviamente “vendonsi” (anche se molti usano scorrettamente la forma singolare: *“vendesi appartamenti”).

Comment: @egreg: non solo nel linguaggio immobiliare. Diciamo nel linguaggio degli annunci (su strada, su periodico e su internet).

Comment: @WalterTross Certamente.

Comment: @mie: Si scrive negli annunci.

Comment: @mie: non capisco che cosa voglia dire con «Ho tolto "mi" con "sempre sembrati" per una una lettura più fluida e più vicina all'italiano parlato». Non mi pare che nell’italiano parlato non si possa usare questo modo d’esprimersi. Dopotutto Charo riportava la sua impressione personale, che è il motivo che l’ha spinta a fare la domanda. Quella frase mi suonava quindi perfettamente corretta. Credo che bisognerebbe correggere gli stranieri solo se il loro modo d’esprimersi è scorretto, innaturale per un madrelingua, involontariamente «arcaico», ecc. Non mi pare sia questo il caso.

Comment: @mie: Sono d'accordo con Ferdinand: penso che così si cambi il senso della mia frase.

Comment: D'accordo con Ferdinand e Charo: @mie, un conto è correggere errori o formulazioni poco chiare, e un altro è modificare una formulazione legittima.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

La posposizione del pronome riflessivo nella terza persona era un tempo molto comune nella lingua scritta. Nella lingua moderna non è più usata se non in forme cristallizzate e, naturalmente, nel linguaggio burocratico o volutamente aulico.

Nei libri di matematica fino a un paio di decenni fa si trovavano spesso frasi come

> Un'equazione di secondo grado dicesi spuria se…
>
> Chiamasi derivata il limite…

La forma *vendesi*, diffusa appunto nella lingua scritta di quel tipo, venne comoda per gli annunci economici che si pagano a parola:

> Vendesi appartamento bicamera termoautonomo
> Affittasi villa vistamare
> Cercasi apprendista patentauto

La forma è rimasta in molti ambiti commerciali, in particolare quello immobiliare. Da notare che *vendesi* è comunemente usato anche per il plurale (*vendesi villette a schiera*) invece del corretto *vendonsi*, a riprova che si tratta di una forma cristallizzata, quasi un complemento più che un verbo: *vendesi appartamento* è come *appartamento in vendita*.

La posposizione è naturalmente viva nel caso del participio, gerundio e infinito: *trasferitosi* *chiamandosi* *lavarsi*. Non più per i tempi finiti; perciò *si recò a Rapallo* e non l'antiquato *recossi a Rapallo*.

---

Nota personale: trovo *vendesi* bruttissimo, molto meglio *casa in vendita*; la forma plurale *vendonsi* è tristissima e orrenda.

Comment: +1 (anche se non trovo molto scientifico qualificare come “orrendo” un fenomeno linguistico...)

Comment: @DaG Infatti è fra parentesi. `;-)`

Comment: @DaG Ho spostato il giudizio in fondo come nota personale, ma alle virgolette attorno a *corretto* ci tengo.

Comment: Personalmente “vendesi” e “vendonsi” (e analoghi) non mi disturbano, anzi le trovo piacevolmente *rétro*, come una vecchia pubblicità o un'insegna di barbiere con le righe colorate che girano, ma il mondo è bello perché è vario. Grazie per aver messo il giudizio a parte.

Comment: @egreg, La posposizione del pronome riflessivo nella terza persona ancora oggi è presente nei testi di matematica, anche moderni. Un esempio tipico che continua ad essere usato in ambito matematico è "come volevasi dimostrare" (http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Come_volevasi_dimostrare)

Comment: @mle Purtroppo!

Comment: @egreg Ho tolto le virgolette a _corretto_, perché la parola cosí virgolettata rischia di essere fraintesa. Posto che l’enclisi del pronome che accompagna un verbo coniugato in un modo finito è tipica dell’italiano antico (in osservanza alla legge di Tobler-Mussafia), se questo verbo ha un soggetto plurale, allora deve essere coniugato al plurale. Il mancato accordo denota o un uso regionale (es. toscano) o, piú probabilmente, l’obliterazione della natura verbale di _vendesi_, come hai giustamente rilevato nella risposta. In ogni caso non può considerarsi corretto.

Comment: @FerdinandBardamu Avevo appositamente messo la parola tra virgolette, perché il concetto di “correttezza” non è definito in modo chiaro. Nelle questioni questioni grammaticali l'uso comanda e (purtroppo) “vendesi appartamenti” si usa. Uso deprecabile, naturalmente, ma che dimostra come la natura verbale di “vendesi” è ormai poco sentita. Rimango dell'opinione che “appartamenti in vendita” sia migliore non solo dal punto di vista grammaticale, ma anche della chiarezza.

Comment: @egreg Che «appartamenti in vendita» sia piú chiaro non è cosí certo. «Vendesi X» è un modulo troppo comune perché qualcuno lo possa equivocare. Certo, «vendesi» è il relitto d’un’antica regola, ripescato per esigenze estralinguistiche e può suscitare reazioni di rigetto. Comunque: l’uso è certamente importante, ma, nel caso specifico, è indubbio che, sotto l’aspetto della mera grammatica, «vendesi appartamenti» sia scorretto (o regionale). Le virgolette, senz’altra precisazione, possono essere ambigue.

Answer (score 6):

In passato gli annunci immobiliari venivano pubblicati come brevi testi dai quotidiani e venivano fatturati a parola, quindi se "vendesi appartamento" erano, diciamo, 200 lire "si vende un appartamento" erano 400 lire.

Answer (score 5):

È possibile incontrare anche le forme "si vende"/"si affitta" ([esempi](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22si%20affitta%20appartamento%22), [esempi](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22si%20vende%20appartamento%22)) però la forma arcaica con il "si" posposto sembra essere ancora la più comune in quest'ambito, probabilmente per le ragioni già spiegate nelle altre risposte.

La forma con il "si" posposto è così comune che esistono cartelli prestampati ([esempio](http://www.marbaro.it/pics/cartello-vendesi-1.jpg)). Ovviamente, nel caso in cui ciò che l'annunciante propone sia plurale, diventano automaticamente incorretti dal punto di vista grammaticale, anche se questo fatto non sembra scoraggiare chi li usa ([esempio](http://trucioli.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Alassio-vendesi-posti-auto.jpg)); e d'altronde non ho mai visto cartelli con prestampato "vendonsi", "affittansi" e similari, anche se non posso escludere che esistano.

Comment: esistono! Basta googlare: http://www.marketingimmobiliare.it/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/foto.jpg (2 in 1 ;) )

Answer (score 1):

"Vendesi" si usa solo nel linguaggio immobiliare (e io credo che sia anche per risparmiare spazio sui cartelli che pubblicizzano la vendita... di solito lo spazio non basta mai, soprattutto se si vuole descrivere con dovizia di particolari l'immobile). Riferito a più immobili si dovrebbe dire "vendonsi" (che suona maluccio), comunque sono termini che si usano solo nella compravendita di immobili, automobili ecc.