# Perché l'uso di "ci" non è corretto (in un contesto particolare)?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, pronouns, particles

In questo [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3566/707) ho scritto la frase «ci si scrive  "vendesi" o "affittasi"», ma poi mi è stata corretta in «si scrive  "vendesi" o "affittasi"», con questo commento alla correzione: «"ci" non si usa/scrive in quella domanda». Ho usato la particella "ci" per sostituire "negli annunci immobiliari italiani", cioè

> *Negli annunci immobiliari italiani* si  scrive  "vendesi" o "affittasi" --> *Ci* si scrive "vendesi" o "affittasi".

Non riesco a capire perché la particella "ci" non si usi in questo contesto. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Rispondo qui perché al momento non riesco a dare una risposta compiuta. L’uso di _ci_ in questo esempio non suona bene nemmeno a me. Forse è dovuto al fatto che questo avverbio locativo si riferisce a un luogo, a un punto ben determinato. Es. «In questo campo [di un modulo] cosa scrivo?» «Ci scrivi il tuo nome».

Comment: @FerdinandBardamu: Ho sempre pensato che l'uso delle particelle «ne» e «ci» in italiano era del tutto analogo all'uso dei "pronoms febles «en» i «hi»" in catalano, ma comincio a vedere che non è così.

Comment: Purtroppo non conosco abbastanza il catalano per esprimermi. Posso dirti che _ci_ (e _vi_, che è la variante di registro piú elevato) ricorrono come locativi («ci vado»), in espressioni idiomatiche («ci vedi?»), col verbo _essere_ («c’è un uomo.»), come dimostrativi (solo _ci_, mai _vi_: «Posso contar_ci_ [=su questo]»; spesso l’uso è pleonastico: «**Con questi soldi** _ci_ campi un mese»), come rafforzativi del verbo _avere_ nel registro colloquiale («Ci ho freddo» pronunciato come «ciò freddo» non «ci-ò freddo»).

Comment: Io, in un registro colloquiale, non avrei molto da ridire sulla presenza del “ci” in una frase così. Semmai, l'unica obiezione potrebbe essere di una certa cacofonia dovuta alla sequenza ci-si-un'altra sillaba con “i”; se la frase fosse stata “ci scrivono ‘vendesi’”, non varrebbe neppure questa obiezione.

Comment: @Dag, se volevi sostituire "negli annunci immobiliari italiani" potevi usare "in questi" molto più semplicemente! (l'uso del "ci" e di altri  segue una regola precisa.. http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronome_personale_in_italiano)

Comment: @mle, non sono sicuro di capire il tuo commento: in che cosa “in questi” sarebbe più semplice di “ci”? Ma soprattutto, fa' attenzione: il “ci” di cui stiamo parlando qui non è il pronome personale, bensì l'avverbio di luogo descritto nell'accezione 2 di [questa voce](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ci1/).

Comment: @mle, per chiarire meglio quello che intendo: in risposta a una frase del tipo «Bisognerebbe fare un salto all'ufficio postale per ritirare la raccomandata», il modo più ovvio per rispondere è «Ci sono già stato», non «Sono già stato in questo», e neppure «Sono già stato lì», no? Al massimo, se si è prolissi, si può ripetere «Sono già stato all'ufficio postale», ma non penso che lo farebbe quasi nessuno. (Certo, ci sono poi altre mille modi per rispondere: «Già fatto!», «Mica aspetto che me lo dici tu» e così via.)

Comment: @karoshi: Dalle tue risposte e dai tuoi commenti penso che tu conosca bene il catalano e quindi sarebbe interessante sapere la tua opinione. In catalano si scriverebbe «s'hi escriu "vendesi" o "affittasi"». «S'hi» corrisponde a «si» + «hi», e «hi» è l'«equivalente» catalano (forse non è del tutto equivalente) della particella «ci». Dire «s'escriu "vendesi" o "affittasi"» sarebbe segnato come un errore, errore commesso molto frequentemente dai madrelingua castigliani perché in castigliano non esiste nessun vocabolo analogo alla particella «ci».

Comment: @charo: non c'è dubbio che in catalano sarebbe "s'hi escriu". In italiano, a me sembrano accettabili entrambe le forme, con e senza il "ci". Tecnicamente, "Negli annunci ci si scrive ..." contiene un pleonasmo, ma è assolutamente d'uso comune.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In questo caso il "ci" sarebbe una ripetizione. Avendo già scritto "negli annunci immobiliari" (complemento di luogo) all'interno della frase, non c'è bisogno di specificare ulteriormente il luogo in cui "si scrive vendesi".

In italiano, la particella "ci" può assumere diversi significati. I più frequenti sono:

- **Avverbio di luogo** (come nella tua frase). Ad esempio:
  "Sto andando dal fornaio."
  "Ci sto andando anche io!"
- **Pronome riflessivo**. Per esempio:
  "Noi ci guardiamo" (ossia "noi guardiamo noi stessi")
- **Pronome dimostrativo**. Ad esempio:
  "Ci ho parlato" (cioè "ho parlato con lui")

**EDIT:** Nei commenti mi è stato fatto notare che la frase "incriminata" non è quella sopra citata, bensì «Gli annunci immobiliari italiani ... sono ... curiosi. Perché ci si scrive "vendesi" o "affittasi"?»

In tal caso l'uso del "ci" non è scorretto, a mio parere. Anche se non è strettamente necessario inserirlo per mantenere il significato della frase, il suo utilizzo non sembra violare alcuna regola grammaticale e sintattica. L'italiano non è una lingua "rigida", secondo me bisogna tollerare (se non incoraggiare) l'uso di queste piccole variazioni all'interno delle frasi. Ognuno ha il suo personale stile di scrittura, con piccole sfumature che lo distinguono da quello di un altro. Perché dunque intraprendere la folle via dell'omologazione?

Comment: Occhio, che non era la stessa frase: la formulazione originaria era «Gli annunci immobiliari italiani mi sono sempre sembrati molto curiosi. Perché ci si scrive "vendesi" o "affittasi" e non "si vende" o "si affitta"?» e quindi è più simile al caso di «Ci sto andando anche io!»

Comment: In tal caso l'uso del "ci" non è scorretto, a mio parere. Anche se non è strettamente necessario inserirlo per mantenere il significato della frase, il suo utilizzo non sembra violare alcuna regola grammaticale e sintattica. L'italiano non è una lingua "rigida", secondo me bisogna tollerare (se non incoraggiare) l'uso di queste piccole variazioni all'interno delle frasi. Ognuno ha il suo personale stile di scrittura, con piccole sfumature che lo distinguono da quello di un altro. Perché dunque intraprendere la folle via dell'omologazione?

Comment: Ciao @leoll2! Dato che il tuo commento ha raggiunto 4 voti, potresti aggiungere il suo contenuto nella tua risposta?